# Accessing JSON object in Handlebars [object Object] error

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

In ember I have a Model like this

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
           model1: ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'],
      model2: [{color:'green'}]
    };
  }
});
```

In handlebars I can access the model 2 like

```
{{#each item in model2}}
<li>{{model2.color}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

How can I access model2 without using {{each}}?

When I use,

```
<li>{{model2.color}}</li>
```

it reurns no value, when I use

```
<li>{{model2}}</li>
```

it shows ***[object Object]*** so how can I access model2 objects without using **{{#each}}**?

JsBin : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tuvozuwa/6/edit
Thanks

Comment: Since `model2` seems to be an array, how about `model2[0].color`?

Comment: @FelixKling nope that seems to give an error the script breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried `{{model2.[0].color}}` and it worked in your context. (Note the dot (`.`) after `model`.)